# How do I set automatic reminder email using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, email

We are running a webinar. I want to send reminder email to all those registered on my site 3 days before the webinar.

The registrant details are in my MySQL and it is a PHP website.

How do I do that?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: 1. setup a cron on your server to run a php script every day 2. set the script to check for webinars starting in three days 3. get the registered users and email them

Comment: Best solution is the one provided by Aaron W. However if you do not have the permission to set cronjobs... you can use programs like phpList -  get the list of emails you want to send....   make schedule in phplist to send an email and it will run at specified schedule.  ----  not the best way but it is an option

Comment: Aaron W.'s solution is a good one, comment if you need more details.

Comment: your question is about the sending email part, the task scheduling part, or both?

Answer (score 4):

PHP can't do that by itself as it is not a program running constantly on a server. It is only run when a user requests a web page. You would need to set up a cron job on the server that calls a PHP script to do the emails.

First, your database would need a field that says whether you have already sent the email or not. Your PHP email script would check if it is 3 days or less until the event, and you have not already sent an email to that person, then send it.

Then you would call that script from a cron job. You can run PHP from the command line, or alternatively use something like `curl` or `wget` to fetch the URL as if you were running the script in a web browser. (That would also mean you can run the cron job from another computer if necessary.)

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for replying to my post! Being a newbie, I find it difficult to understand the process. The current process is that, we get the details from the registration page(php) and save them in a separate table. As soon as as someone registered, an email will be sent saying "Thanking for registering" Now what is a cron job? What should I do with that? I have access to the FTP and DB. Can you please help me out?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_job for an overview - you would need access to your server to set one up. So if you do not have that, then you would have to set up a cron job (or Scheduled Task in Windows) on your own computer.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cronjob to run a reminder script at a specific time 3 days before your webinar. Your script would loop through your user data and send email using some variation of php's [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Not sure what your server type is but if you are running cPanel here is a link to their docs on how to set up a cron job:
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/CronJobs

Let us know which of the above you're not sure about and we can provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have built-in schedulers.

You should consider using [`cron`](http://drupal.org/cron) on unix/linux

or

[`Schedulers`](http://drupal.org/node/31506) on Windows

or

There are some [online crons](http://www.setcronjob.com/) available.

which will call your php-scripts. (which will internally do the task of mailing)

Note: the links above refer to drupal sites, but explanations given there with regards to cron and schedulers are applicable in pure-php.